# How to zero tmInternalLeading for Font in Delphi VCL

Tags: windows, delphi, fonts

I have a Windows based Delphi 10.2.3 application where I want to change the "tmLeadingInternal" and "tmLeadingExternal" properties for a font. The font is created on the fly by creating a TLogFont and assigning that to the relevant canvas.

I can retrieve these properties OK with GetTextMetrics, and the Microsoft documentation says "The designer may set this member to zero". However, I cannot see a way to do this in Delphi.

Comment: The "designer", I believe, is the font designer.

Comment: @Sertac - hmmm - I suspect you are correct in which case it's a no go.

Comment: I don't quite understand, however, what does the designer have to do with external leading. There's nothing there, no accent, diacritics etc..

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: External leading concerns the spacing (outside the font itself) between lines when text wraps to multiple lines, IIRC. No drawing of any sort is allowed in that space, and a font designer can specify that a minimum spacing is allowed between lines for the intended legibility. Many fonts don't provide this value, so that the software can control the line spacing. (I could be remembering wrong, though.

Comment: @Ken - You are right in that the external is a component of the "line spacing" and I suppose one could want no space between the bottom of the descent part and the internal leading of the next row.

Comment: @TomB: I suppose one could, but that doesn't mean the font designer had the same thoughts. :-) Sertac was right, though - the docs you quoted are referring to the designer of the font being able to specify zero. As that value is embedded in the font itself, it's not changeable at runtime. You'd have to actually modify the font file to do so.